# Kalman filter for visual tracking of a ball sliding on a gutter

Tags: python, computer-vision, filtering, signal-processing, kalman-filter

I'm working on a project where  a  robot  needs  to keep  a  ball  at  a  desired  position  on  a  gutter.  The  gutter  is fixed  at  one  end  and  held  at  the  other  end  by  the  robot’s effector  which  therefore  decides  of  its  orientation  and,  as a consequence,  of  the  position  of  the  ball. The robot's effector can move up or down vertically. The robot's controller is deep learning based and was trained in simulation. Once trained I deployed it on the physical robot to perform the task on the real world. The position of the ball and velocity of the ball are both needed by the controller. The ball position is obtained through visual tracking with a low quality webcam which means that the observations are noisy. The velocity is obtained by computing the difference in ball position between two timesteps (~0.1s). However, noise in the ball position produce large error in the velocity computation. Even if the controller is performing ok with noisy observations, I'd like to improve it. So I started looking into the Kalman filter.

My state is composed of the ball position (1d) and velocity (1d), however I'm measuring the ball position only with the camera. My state model looks like this :

[image]

with

[image]

For the command U, I considered 4 cases and derived the acceleration for each :

[image: manip]

u is the effector height (which is controlled) below or above the equilibrium position of the gutter and [image] = 0.06 is the friction coefficient plastic/plastic (both ball and gutter are in plastic) that I found to be given the most realstic behavior (see figure below). In code i'm checking the sign of [image] and [image] to know which equation to use. I recorded a trajectory of the robot performing the task to validate the model (prediction step). However, the model doesn't seems to be very accurate : [image: prediction]. The predicted ball position doesn't fi the true (measured) position a all. However the predicted speed is smoother than the naively computed one (measured). So my first question is : Is something wrong with my prediction step ? Even when adding air friction the predicted ball trajectory is still very wrong. Anyway, I tried to add the Update step to see how it goes :

- **Process covariance matrix**

[image]

With :

[image]

I chose the value of Q without knowing too much what to put.

- **kalman Gain**

[image]

where :

H and R are the identity matrix.

- **Correction**

[image]

where :

[image]. Since I can't directly measure it, I put [image].

But once again, things doesn't behave nicely :[image: kf]. The kalman filtered position is not smoothed and the kalman filtered velocity doesn't make sense. I have a hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong. I suspect that the prediction step is not right and that I should choose more fitted values for R and Q, but I don't really understand their role and how to chose them. Did I used the kalman filter correclty ? Where did I screwed up ? In case the problem is due to my implementation here is my code :

```
def kf_predict(X, P, A, Q, B, U):
    X = dot(A, X) + dot(B, U)
    P = dot(A, dot(P, A.T)) + Q
    return(X,P) 


error_est_pos = 3
error_est_vel = 2
error_mes_pos = 1
dt = 0.1
g = 9.81 * 100
theta = 0
mu = 0.06
# Initialization of state matrices
X = np.array([[0.25*56], [0.0]])
P = np.diag((error_est_pos**2, error_est_vel**2))
A = np.array([[1, dt], [0, 1]])
Q = 0.1*np.eye(X.shape[0])
B = np.array([[1/2*(dt*dt)],[dt]])

# Measurement matrices
Y = np.array([ball_pos[0] + 0*np.random.randn(1)[0]])
H = np.identity(2)
R = np.diag([error_mes_pos**2]) 
d = 45
for obs,u in zip(ball_pos,effec_pos):
    theta = np.arctan(u/d)
    tmp = np.abs(theta)
    if X[1] == 0 and u ==0:
        U = np.array(0)
    else : 
        if theta * X[1][0]  >= 0 and theta >= 0: # case 1
            U = np.array(g*(np.sin(tmp) - mu*np.cos(tmp)))
        elif theta * X[1][0]  < 0 and theta >= 0: # case 2
            U = np.array(g*(np.sin(tmp) + mu*np.cos(tmp)))
        elif theta * X[1][0]  < 0 and theta <= 0:  # case 3
            U =  np.array(g*( - np.sin(tmp) - mu*np.cos(tmp)))
        elif theta * X[1][0]  >= 0 and theta <= 0: # case 4
            U =  np.array(g*( - np.sin(tmp) + mu*np.cos(tmp)))
    (X, P) = kf_predict(X, P, A, Q, B, U)
     # Calculating the Kalman Gain
    S = H.dot(P).dot(H.T) + R
    K = P.dot(H).dot(inv(S))
    Y = np.array([[obs +  np.random.randn(1)[0]],[0.0]])
    # Update the State Matrix
    # Combination of the predicted state, measured values, covariance matrix and Kalman Gain
    X = X + K.dot(Y - H.dot(X))
    # Update Process Covariance Matrix
    P = (np.identity(len(K)) - K.dot(H)).dot(P)
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or solutions.

Comment: One minor note. You do not need to consider 4 cases, but can just write `U = np.array(g*(np.sin(theta) - np.sign(X[1][0])*mu*np.cos(theta)))` instead